# How to bind and unbind context to $document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events

I got something like this, and it worked as expected:

```
$document.on('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this));
```

Without `bind(this)`, the `this` inside `clickHandler` would point to document object so that's why I put it there. However it behaved incorrectly when I tried to unbind it. I have tried with the following:

```
$document.off('click',  this.clickHandler);

$document.off('click',  this.clickHandler.bind(this));

$document.unbind('click', this.clickHandler);
```

None of them work as what I expect. I want to remove the specific click event handler (together with its `this` context) out of `$document`. For example, I want to do that in `$scope.$destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with:

```
$document.off('click',  this.clickHandler).unbind();
```